# IMU: What is the "w" in the IMU data

Tags: ros, imu, gazebo, ros-kinetic, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,
i use the Gazebo IMU-Plugin to generate sensor data of an IMU for my robot.
An IMU message looks like the following:

```
header: ...
orientation:
x: -9.881865455454e-324
y: -9.881865455454e-324
z: 8.8755655245457e-17
w: 1.0
orientation_covariance ...
```

I understand the x,y,z koordinates, but what does that "w" mean?

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302275/imu:-what-is-the-%22w%22-in-the-imu-data/) by [vonunwerth](https://answers.ros.org/users/34864/vonunwerth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2018-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's the fourth component of a [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation). (You don't have to fully understand the math behind it, it's roughly a rotation axis and a corresponding rotation angle around this axis). See also: [tf2/quaternions](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions)

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2018-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-04**:
Just as a clarification: @vonunwerth: the entire `orientation` field is a [Quaternion](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Quaternion.html).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quaternion is a type of mathematical notation. It is not the same thing as a vector, but similar concepts can be expressed with it. You can imagine it like a Struct or a data type that has 4 variables, one of them has the name "w".

this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/d4EgbgTm0Bg) explains the concept of a quaternion in  a visual way.

---

Originally posted by [Wifi-cable](https://answers.ros.org/users/51566/wifi-cable/) with karma: 11 on 2020-02-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answers above may have explained it well.
But as an addition: **x, y, z** over there are not coordinates of some point, they are stating the **axis of rotation**.
A quaternion := (x, y, z, w), in which (x, y, z) is scaled with sin(theta/2), and w := cos(theta/2), in which **theta** is the **angle of rotation**.

---

Originally posted by [zihao](https://answers.ros.org/users/50803/zihao/) with karma: 33 on 2020-02-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1